# squidGuard: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-6.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 12.04, installation

I tried to install `squidGuard-1.4`. I successfully install but I can't load it using this command `squidGuard -d` 
it turn out like this result:

```
squidGuard: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-6.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What are the solution for this kind of error?

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Heloo, may be, you can test, this command.

```
root@proxy-serv:~ # apt-file search libdb-6.0.so
libdb6.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-6.0.so

root@proxy-serv:~ # ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-6.0.so
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-6.0.so: No such file or directory

root@proxy-serv:~ # cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
root@proxy-serv:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ln -s /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.6.0/lib/libdb-6.0.so ./
```

Done.

Answer (score -1):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libdb-6.0.so/parent_dir
```

and try again